# My precooked vacuum sealed ham was left in garage at 45 degrees Overnight is it still good to make

Tags: ham

Left my precooked vacuum sealed ham out in 45 degree garage over night is it still good to make

Comment: That rather depends on whether Fahrenheit or Celsius.

Comment: Also depends on how it's supposed to be stored. I've seen precooked heavily processed ham that's stored unrefrigerated in stores. That would be fine. Something that's supposed to be refrigerated, not so much.